# Dirac delta inner product preserved under the Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I have the following inner product:
$$\langle \delta_y, f \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \delta(x-y)f^*(x)\,dx = f^*(y)$$

For it a property similar to Plancherel's theorem can be shown with respect to the Fourier transform even though the Dirac delta is not in $L_1$:

$$f^*(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \delta(x-y)f^*(x)\,dx  = \langle \delta_y, f \rangle$$

$$ f^*(y) = \overline{\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\hat{f}](y)} = \overline{\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \exp(2\pi i \langle u, y \rangle)\hat{f}(u)\,du} = $$
$$ = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\exp(-2\pi i \langle u,y\rangle)\hat{f}^*(u)\,du = \langle \hat{\delta_y}, \hat{f} \rangle$$

Where $\hat{\cdot}$ and $\mathcal{F}[\cdot]$ represents the Fourier transform.

Is there some formalization of this?

Now if I consider the identity $\langle\delta_y,\hat{f}\rangle = \langle\hat{\delta}_y,f\rangle$ instead, then it also holds:

$$\hat{f}^*(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\delta(u-y)\hat{f}^*(u)\,du = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\exp(-2\pi i \langle x, y\rangle)f^*(x)\,dx = \hat{f}^*(y)$$

In that case even if $f=\delta_z$, then:

$$\langle \delta_y, \hat{\delta}_z \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\delta(x-y)\exp(-2\pi i \langle x, z \rangle)\,dx = \exp(-2\pi i \langle y, z \rangle)$$

References on the subject are welcome.

Edit: I had a mistake with conjugation.

Comment: I guess the objects you should look at are "tempered distributions" which allow to formally extend Fourier analysis into a much richer world.

Comment: For a tempered distribution $T$ its Fourier transform is defined by $<\hat{T},\phi>=<T,\hat{\phi}>$ for all Schwartz function $\phi$. With the Fourier inversion theorem this is equivalent to $<\hat{T},\hat{\varphi}(-.)>=<T,\varphi>$, adding complex conjugates you get your result. If it works it is because the Fourier transform is continuous from the Schwartz space to itself, for the Schwartz space topology (that tempered distributions are continuous for).

Comment: @reuns Does $f$ need to be a Schwartz function? Even if it is discontinuous, won't the above expression still hold? If it does not, where is the mistake in my derivation?

Comment: $\delta$ is compactly supported and its Fourier transform is bounded so you can extend for its particular distribution to : $f$ inverse Fourier transform of a $L^1$ function (thus continuous).To extend to a non-integrable $\hat{f}$ you need to take a particular sequence (of $L^1$ functions) converging to it and be careful (this is the topic of the proofs of the Fourier inversion theorem)

Comment: @reuns You can formulate your comments as an answer so I can accept it. Also you mentioned that my result follows from the identity: $\langle T, \phi \rangle = \langle \hat{T}, \hat{\phi}(-.) \rangle$ by applying complex conjugation. But then I get $\langle T^*, \phi^* \rangle = \langle \hat{T}^*, \hat{\phi}^*(-.) \rangle$ which is equivalent to $\langle T^*, \phi \rangle = \langle \hat{T}^*, \hat{\phi} \rangle$ only if $\phi$ is real. Am I missing something?

Comment: @reuns Also about the continuity question - the statement should hold also for functions which the discontinuities are limited to set of measure zero, right? Also what about the $f=\delta_z$ case?

Comment: For distributions (in contrary to the $L^2$ inner product) the pairing is $\Bbb{C}$ linear  in $\phi$ ie. $\langle T,\phi\rangle = \int_{R^d} T(x)\phi(x)dx$. The $f=\delta_z$ case doesn't make sense.

Comment: @reuns So no conjugation I take it. That still doesn't explain how one gets rid of the minus, if $\phi$ is not real. By $f = \delta_z$, I meant the equation I had above: $\langle \delta_y, \hat{\delta}_z \rangle = \exp(-2\pi i \langle y, z \rangle)$.